# Munin with intermittent clients

Tags: linux, monitoring, munin

I'm currently using munin to monitor a bunch of linux servers (as well as a few WinXP clients). However, munin does its data collection sequentially, and seems to be very susceptible to timing out when clients disconnect in the middle.

Are there any parallel versions?

Is there any way to handle the case of a disconnected client quicker?

Right now, many of my data collection tasks take longer than the 5 minutes until the next collection starts, leading to both warnings and missed data points.

Comment: I strongly recommend you consider using something else besides munin to do your monitoring.  I struggled with it mightily at my last job with a few dozens of servers and workstations.  The 5 minute hard data collection window is the limiting factor if you have any devices (particularly snmp devices) that are slow to respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `munin-update` should use `--fork` which "if set, will fork off one process for each host." Check whether your distribution didn't disable it.

Also, to reduce time spent waiting on dead clients, you can use `--timeout` to reduce the timeout for a host.

Comment: You surely mean to "increase", not "reduce" the time before timeout happens. I don't have enough rep. to edit myself, sorry.

Comment: @milan: thanks for the hint, but i intended it as written. I clarified the post. is it better now?